# Theorem 2.44 Folland

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

$\textbf{Theorem:}$ Suppose $T \in GL(n,\mathbb{R})$. If $f$ is a Lebesgue measurable function on $\mathbb{R}^n$, so is $f \circ T$. If $f$ is integrable then

$$ \int f(x)dx = \vert \text{det}(T) \vert \int f \circ T(x)dx $$

$\textbf{Proof:}$ It suffices to prove when $T=T_i, i=1,2,3$ where

$$T_1(x_1,\ldots,x_j,\ldots,x_n)=(x_1,\ldots,cx_j,\ldots ,x_n)$$

$$T_2(x_1,\ldots,x_j,\ldots,x_n)=(x_1,\ldots,x_j+cx_k,\ldots ,x_n)$$

$$T_3(x_1,\ldots,x_j,\ldots,x_k,\ldots,x_n)=(x_1,\ldots,x_k,\ldots,x_j,\ldots,x_n) $$

It is easily verified that $\text{det}(T_1)=c, \text{det}(T_2)=1$ and $\text{det}(T_3)=-1$. We have

$$f \circ T_1(x_1,\ldots,x_j,\ldots,x_n)=f(x_1,\ldots,cx_j,\ldots ,x_n)$$

So define $h: \mathbb{R}^{n-1} \times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ by:

$$ h((x_1,\ldots,x_{j-1},x_{j+1},\ldots,x_{n-1}),x_n)=f((x_1,\ldots,cx_j,\ldots ,x_n)$$

Use Fubini:

$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f\circ T_1(x)dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} h(x)dx= \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n-1}} \left( \int_{\mathbb{R}} h_{\overline{y}}(cx_j)dx_j \right) dx_1 dx_2 \ldots dx_n  $$

$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f \circ T_1(x)dx= \dfrac{1}{\vert c \vert}\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n-1}} \left( \int_{\mathbb{R}} h_{\overline{y}}(x_j)dx_j \right) dx_1 dx_2 \ldots dx_n = \dfrac{1}{\vert c \vert} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(x)dx  $$

where $\overline{y}=(x_1,\ldots,x_{j-1},x_{j+1},\ldots,x_{n-1})$ and

$$h_{\overline{y}}(x_j)=h((x_1,\ldots,x_{j-1},x_{j+1},\ldots,x_{n-1}),x_n)$$

Similarly for $T_2$. In the case of $T_3$ I couldn't solve it. Any hint? Is my attempt correct?.

Answer (score 1):

It suffices to consider the fact that the Lebesgue measure respects the symmetry of swapping coordinates. That is, consider $S$ a measurable set. Define $S' = \{(x_1, ..., x_j, ..., x_k, ..., x_n) : (x_1, ..., x_k, ..., x_j, ..., x_n) \in S\}$. Then $S$ and $S'$ have the same measure. Thus, $\chi_S$ and $\chi_{S'}$ have the same integral. And $\chi_S = \chi_{S'} \circ T_3$. This allows one to prove the result for simple functions and then extend the result to all functions.